# Purpose of と in しゅつどのようとふめいひん

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I am wondering which of its roles the と fulfills in the following sentence found in a Hiragana Times article. The sentence is the name of an exhibition:

> 「ー奈良市出土**のようと**不名品ー」

The のよう part I only know as "like/similar", usually in the form of のような・のように.

The only explanation for と I can think of, that applies here, is in its quotation form. As if someone had left out another set of quotation marks:

> 「奈良市出土のよう」と不名品

I've never seen と used like this though, without it being followed by a verb such as 言う for example.

**-- EDIT**

Someone posted a comment that then disappeared. They asked if maybe it could be 用途 or something similar.

The article was actually only using hiragana. I added the Kanji to make it easier to read but I might have inadvertently removed some crucial information in doing so. **Here's the actual, original sentence from the Magazine**

> ２０２２ねん１０がつついたちから１１がつまつに、ならしまいぞうぶんかざいちょうさセンターで 「また！ナニこれ？
> ー**ならししゅつどのようとふめいひん**ー」がかいさいされました。

The translation given:

> From October 1st to the end of November 2022, the Nara Municipal
> Buried Cultural Properties Research Centre held an exhibition titled
> "Again! What is this? - Unknown Objects Excavated in Nara City."

Comment: It's 奈良市出土の用途不明品.

Comment: "Get rid of Kanji" they said. "Japanese could do well with only hiragana/katakana." They said. Those who claim Kanji is not essential to Japanese has no in-depth understanding of the language whatsoever. They do not see the profundity thereof.

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in a [comment](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/99394/purpose-of-%E3%81%A8-in-%E3%81%97%E3%82%85%E3%81%A4%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%E3%81%B5%E3%82%81%E3%81%84%E3%81%B2%E3%82%93?noredirect=1#comment161795_99394). This has nothing to do with the grammatical concept of のような・のように and was, instead, just a matter of incorrectly converting Hiragana text to Kanji.

The correct conversion would be:

> 奈良市出土**の用途**不明品

The bold part is the correct Kanji equivalent of のようと from the original paragraph.